How to add a spatial network in pytorch
I have been looking into machine and deeplearning models in the Geospatial field. Though I can find plenty of examples using sattelite imagery, I cannot find much relating to vector data.
What I would like to try is have a model predict where to set points on a line-network based on a starting point or line.
The closest I have come to understanding what a model in pytorch would look something like this:
class PointPredictionModel(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim, num_outputs):
    super(PointPredictionModel, self).__init__()
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_dim, 64)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(64, 128)
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(128, 64)
    self.fc4 = nn.Linear(64, output_dim * num_outputs)  # Output will be flattened

def forward(self, x):
    x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
    x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
    x = torch.relu(self.fc3(x))
    x = self.fc4(x)
    return x.view(-1, num_outputs, output_dim)  # Reshape to (batch_size, num_outputs, output_dim)

Where:

input_dim: Dimension of the input point vector.
output_dim: Dimension of each output point vector.
num_outputs: Number of points to predict.

What I would like to know is if it is possible to add the line-network to the input like a second parameter.
Should I add for each set in the training data the whole line-network, if not how would I have to adapt the dataloader?
